# Ошибка при работе с указателями(Lazarus)

Tags: указатели, pascal, lazarus

Ошибка при работе с указателями(Lazarus). Ошибка illegal qualifier. Код взят из методички, данной для выполнения. Погуглив, понял, что скорее всего я пытаюсь работать, как с указателем, но по факту это не он. Не могу понять в чем именно ошибка. Первая мысль была, что ошибка в "домиках" перед названиями, но метод "тыка" тут не помог. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Привожу скрины
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Point1^.Data.X`

Comment: @zed, спасибо, работает